# Core Data Managed Object attributes returns null

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

This is probably a really simple question. I have a bunch of stuff in a sql lite db. I can retrieve that stuff and store it to an array just fine. When i iterate through that array with a `for (MyCustomMo *mo in myDataArray)` i can access the managed objects attributes just fine with e.g. mo.name.

So far everything is working ok, but...

Later when i get an object from that same array with `[myDataArray objectAtIndex:index]` i get a MyCustomMo* but when i try to access the attributes of that object i get null. Do i need to use `[myDataArray objectAtIndex]` somehow differently?

Comment: did you try to force the retain of the object? it may be happening that the object is released from the memory somehow

Comment: How much "later"? What has happened in the meantime? What do you see if you log the value of the object you get out of the array the second time?

Comment: @holographix I'm using ARC, if that matters. I don't have the code at hand right now, sorry.

Comment: @jrturton I retrieve the array in viewDidLoad and TableViewController uses it to populate rows. So, the delay is some milliseconds.

Comment: can you tell where are you using this `for (MyCustomMo *mo in myDataArray)` and `[myDataArray objectAtIndex:index]`.. might be they are in two different class

Comment: @InderKumarRathore They're in the same class. It's the basic TableViewController setup where data is loaded in viewDidLoad method and the data is used in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @JHollanti.. please add some code. 1. where you are adding values in this array. 2. for loop where you are successfully accessing the property

Comment: Okay, i got it. The reason it wasn't working was 'cause i was using a local ManagedObjectContext in viewDidLoad. I didn't come to think that ManagedObject needs the ManagedObjectContext when it lazily loads attributes. Sorry for wasting everyones time and thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, i got it. The reason it wasn't working was 'cause i was using a local ManagedObjectContext in viewDidLoad. I didn't come to think that ManagedObject needs the ManagedObjectContext when it lazily loads attributes.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and sharing your solution. I wasn't aware of the lazy loading in CoreData, the solution to my similar problem seems so obvious now!

Comment: My pleasure :) Glad it was of use to someone.